# gb4e: use of hash sign in front of semantically incorrect examples

Tags: gb4e

I am working on a linguistic thesis and use the `gb4e` package to number my examples. I have been taught that semantically incorrect examples should be marked by a hash sign in front of them, so I am sure it will be accepted in my university department.

However, I get an error message that says

> "Illegal parameter number in definition of `\@itemlabel`."

when I try to use the hash sign. How can I fix this?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}

Oft-cited example by Noam Chomsky:

\begin{exe}
\ex
    \begin{xlist}
    \ex[??] {Colorless green ideas sleep furiously.} % This is allowed by gb4e.
    \ex[#] {Colorless green ideas sleep furiously.} % This one yields an error.
    \end{xlist}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\#` to print the symbol. It is an internal command (as `%,{,},\,_,^` also).

Answer (score 2):

The solution in Sigur's comment above is working for me:

> Use `\#` to print the symbol. It is an internal command (as `%,{,},\,_,^` also).